# Munkres, Topology, section 37, question 1

Tags: general-topology

[Maximal set with respect to the finite intersection property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315587/maximal-set-with-respect-to-the-finite-intersection-property)

Here, the accepted answer mentions (c) is false as stated. However, I don't understand why the following proof is incorrect:

Suppose $a,b$ are two points in $\cap D$ over each D in $\mathscr{D}$. Since X is T1, there is a nbd $U$ of $a$ not containing $b$. $a \in D$, hence $a \in \bar{D}$. By part a of the exercise, each nbd of $a$ lies in $\mathscr{D}$, which is a contradiction since $b$ is not in this nbd. Therefore there cannot be two points in the intersection.

Comment: But it's the intersection of the closures, and $b$ can belong to the closure of each neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. Is this proof correct if the question is modified to say intersection over just the elements of $\mathscr{D}$ and not their closures?

Comment: Yes, but in that case we don't need any conditions of the space, and a simpler argument shows that the intersection of a maximal family with the FIP is empty or a singleton. If $\bigcap D$ contains (at least) two points $a\neq b$, then we can adjoin $X\setminus \{b\}$ to the family and keep the FIP (even the total intersection remains nonempty), so it wasn't maximal.

Comment: Got it, thanks.